# Four Directions #17 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

To the East is a place where arrows may flow
To the West you may see Beelzebub hitching a ride
To the North is a view if your vision's not clouded
To the South is a place where languages were born

I'm known for my color and was named for my diminutive residents
Where and what am I?

Hint #1:

> To the South is a namesake of a prideful endeavor.

Comment: Is using "flow" rather than "fly" intentional?

Comment: Definitely intentional

Comment: looking forward to #18...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [Lake Louise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Louise_(Alberta)) in Alberta

To the East is a place where arrows may flow

> [Bow River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bow_River)

To the West you may see Beelzebub hitching a ride

> [Devil's Thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devils_Thumb)

To the North is a view if your vision's not clouded

> [Cataract Peak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataract_Peak)

To the South is a place where languages were born

> [Mount Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Babel_(Alberta)) (in Genesis, the Tower of Babel is used to describe why people speak different languages, this is part of the hint).

I'm known for my color and was named for my diminutive residents

> Lake Louise is also known as "Lake of Little Fishes" and is known for its distinctive turquoise colour.

Comment: Nice!  You have all four directional clues correct!  The final answer is not, but I think a small amount of searching will get you there.  It’s a small area to search now haha.  The two clues on the actual location should be pretty obvious when you find it.

Comment: Also, the south hint is just another clue for the same place.  The reason it was built, etc. in the story.

Comment: @MetaZen I think I've got it now, can't believe I didn't see that the first time.

Comment: That's not the answer, though I can see why you found it!  It seems outside the bounds of the four direction.  The answer is right in the small area within the four directional clues.  May take a tiny bit of research for the second part of the clue.

Comment: @MetaZen Okay, I've changed the answer again, I'm pretty sure I've got it this time.

Comment: That’s it!  Nicely done.  This one was a little more vague than others I’ve done.  Which clue got you to the general area first?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is the answer(The answer is based on the written directions):

**line 1:**

> To the East is a place where arrows may flow

means:

> An English city called Lincoln,The name derives from the Latin words-"**Lindum Colonia**", which means a camp of Roman soldiers-And if that was the name, there must have been some arrows in the past.

**line 2:**

> To the West you may see Beelzebub hitching a ride

means:

> **Beelzebub** this word is a hint to the book "Lord of the Flies",This book tells about a group of British children who found themselves on a deserted island.

**line 3**

> To the North is a view if your vision's not clouded

means:

> **a view** is "Yorkshire Dales" National Park in Northern England-The park has the most beautiful view and it has waterfalls, caves and a delightful view ,**"if your vision's not clouded"**-The weather should be good so you can enjoy this place.

**line 4:**

> To the South is a place where languages were born

means:

> The word "languages" refers to English, which, according to studies, is based on some dialects:Elizabethan English,r-full dialects.Which were known to have been created in England many years ago. [image] [image] In the pictures below you can see the places where the various dialect speakers at the end of the day created the language that everyone speaks today.For a detailed explanation look here: https://www.languagesoftheworld.info/historical-linguistics/thus-spoke-shakespeare-or-did-he.html

**line 5:**

> I'm known for my color and was named for my diminutive residents

means:

> my color-red,Liverpool Football Club -Fans of this club are called "**Reds**".**"named for my diminutive residents"**-diminutive residents mean to "Lilliput"- Whose name is  the name of the city from the novel "Gulliver's Travels"-A city whose people were small, and some say that the story in which it was mentioned hints parodically-political about England and France in the early 18th century.

So this is the answer:

> **Where am I**:**Liverpool**- the English city **what am I**:**"Liverpool F.C."**- the English men's football club.

Comment: I really like the approach and associations, but this is not the place I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The OP said that this was not he/she had in mind, but I still wanted to post this here:

To the East is a place where arrows may flow

> ?

To the West you may see Beelzebub hitching a ride

> **Thebes, Egypt** [Ancient Egyptian capital at around 1700BC]
>  **WHY?**
>  Beelzebub --> flies --> one of the 10 plagues --> at around 1700 BC --> took place at Thebes

To the North is a view if your vision's not clouded

> **Mount Sinai, Egypt** [where Moses got the 10 commandments from God, who was covered by **clouds** then]

To the South is a place where languages were born

> Before the edit, it was "where language was born": first language: Egyptian, at c. 2690 BC; capital at that time was **Umm El Qa'ab**

I'm known for my color and was named for my diminutive residents
Where and what am I?

> ?

Comment: This isn’t the place, but the approach is good.  To answer your questions above, the news article is not related and I’d rather not speak to whether that large of an area is related (at least not yet).